# QTableWidget itemDoubleClicked signal link to textEdit

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

i have a populated tableWidget and i want to select the row header upon doubleClick and grab the text in the row header then populate a textEdit with it.

i have:

```
        connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidget*)),ui->textEdit, SLOT(on_tableWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)));

void on_tableWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem *item)
{
    QString selectedName = item->text();
    ui->textEdit->setText(selectedName);
}
```

and not only is the focus not changing when i run the code buh nothing is happening to the textEdit... Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection should be

```
connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidget*)),
        this, SLOT(on_tableWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)));
```

provided that the slot is defined in your class.

Answer (score 0):

With the slot name format ("`on_widgetName_signalName`") and because the `tableWidget` belongs to a generated ui, the connection should be done automatically by the line `ui->setupUi(this);` you have in your constructor.

So, you can remove the `connect` call, but you should check that `on_tableWidget_itemDoubleClicked` is declared as a slot, and that the macro `Q_OBJECT` was included in the class definition.